# Execute this jquery only when viewport is bigger than

Tags: jquery, viewport

I want this jquery to be executed only when the viewport width is bigger than 1024px:

```
$(function(){
$(".pic").hover(function(){   
  $(this).find(".textimage").fadeIn(100);
}
                ,function(){
                    $(this).find(".textimage").fadeOut(100);
                }
               );  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see you're new to SO, You will usually catch flak for just asking a question without telling us what you've done or what you've tried to do or learn.  Normally people don't get responses without that.

simple:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if(winWidth >= 1024){
        $(".pic").hover(function(){   
            $(this).find(".textimage").fadeIn(100);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find(".textimage").fadeOut(100);
        });
    }
});
```

Then you can add this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if(winWidth >= 1024){
        $(".pic").hover(function(){   
            $(this).find(".textimage").fadeIn(100);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find(".textimage").fadeOut(100);
        });
    } else {
        $('.pic').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. The only thing it's that if I resize the window lower than 1024, then go back to bigger than 1024, this functions doesn't work. However, if I refresh it on the specified viewport size it's working. Should that bother me?

Comment: If I add the resize it doesn't work that well.. when I keep resizing the window it will execute the function when the viewport is lower than 1024

Comment: @mrryphel, I've edited the answer above to unbind the hover event when the window size is less than 1024